# How do i summarize values attributed to several variables in a data set?

Tags: r, dplyr

First of all I have to describe my data set. It has three columns, where number 1 is country, number 2 is date (%Y-%m-%d), and number 3 is a value associated with each row (average hotel room prices). It continues like that in rows from 1990 to 2019. It works as such:

```
Country  Date        Value
France   2011-01-01  700
```

etc.

I'm trying to turn the date into years instead of the normal %Y-%m-%d format, so it will instead sum the average values for each country each year (instead of each month). How would I go about doing that?

I thought about summarizing the values totally for each country each year, but that is hugely tedious and takes a long time (plus the code will look horrible). So I'm wondering if there is a better solution for this problem that I'm not seeing.

Here is the task at hand so far. My dataset `priceOnly` shows the average price for each month. I have also attributed it to show only values not equal to 0.

```
diffyear <- priceOnly %>%
group_by(Country, Date) %>%
summarize(averagePrice = mean(Value[which(Value!=0.0)]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `lubridate` package to extract years and then summarise accordingly.
Something like this:

```
diffyear <- priceOnly %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(Date)) %>% 
  filter(Value > 0) %>% 
  group_by(Country, Year) %>% 
  summarize(averagePrice = mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

And in general, you should always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your questions.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry about not providing enough code, i was just looking for a concept rather than a specific problem with my code. Therefore i thought i wouldn't need to provide much (and rather explain it). I am still new here, so i will do better in the future!

Comment: No worries! The only thing is that people tend to downvote or ignore questions where there's no example as it's typically harder to answer such questions and test the code. And we can't really be sure that the problem doesn't lie with the data.